# No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule' after upgrade from Angular 5 to Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

Our dev team recently updated an Angular 5 project to Angular 7.  I've downloaded the repo and I'm trying to build the source, however when I run the **ng build** command I get a **ERROR in No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'**.

[image]

If I run the **ng --version** command it shows the following:

- Angular CLI: 7.3.6
- Node: 11.10.0
- OS: win32 x64
- Angular: 7.2.10

The **app.module.ts** file is:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AdminComponent } from './layout/admin/admin.component';
import { AdminComponent1 } from './layout/admin1/estimate.component';
import { AuthComponent } from './layout/auth/auth.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';
import { MenuItems } from './shared/menu-items/menu-items';
import { BreadcrumbsComponent } from './layout/admin/breadcrumbs/breadcrumbs.component';
import { ServicesProvider } from '../providers/services';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthGuardService } from './activate-guard';
import { AuthLoginService } from './deactivate-guard';
import { SupperAdmin } from './supperadmin-guard';
import { NgProgressModule } from 'ngx-progressbar';
import {SimpleNotificationsModule} from 'angular2-notifications';
import { ConfigService } from '../assets/config/ConfigService';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AdminComponent,
    AdminComponent1,
    AuthComponent,
    BreadcrumbsComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    NgProgressModule,
    SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
    BrowserModule,


  ],
  providers: [MenuItems, ServicesProvider, AuthGuardService, SupperAdmin, AuthLoginService,  NgProgressModule, ConfigService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

and the **main.ts** file is:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

And the index.html is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Welcome</title>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=xxx"></script>
<!-- <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"
async defer></script> -->
  <!-- <script src="../src/assets/js/pdf.js"></script>
  <script src="../src/assets/js/pdf.worker.js"></script> -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimal-ui">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="description" content="Visual Estimator" />
  <meta name="keywords" content="visualestimator" />
  <meta name="author" content="phoenixcoded" />
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <style>
  </style>
  <!-- Google font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ng2-toastr@4.1.2/ng2-toastr.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <app-root>
    <div class="theme-loader">
      <div class="loader-track">
        <div class="preloader-wrapper">
          <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue">
            <div class="circle-clipper left">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gap-patch">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle-clipper right">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="spinner-layer spinner-red">
            <div class="circle-clipper left">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gap-patch">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle-clipper right">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="spinner-layer spinner-yellow">
            <div class="circle-clipper left">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gap-patch">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle-clipper right">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="spinner-layer spinner-green">
            <div class="circle-clipper left">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="gap-patch">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="circle-clipper right">
              <div class="circle"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </app-root>
</body>
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/plugins/leaflet-image/v0.0.4/leaflet-image.js'></script>
<script>
</script>
</html>
```

And the **angular.json** file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "mega-able": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/marker-icon.png",
              "src/marker-icon-2x.png"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome-scss/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw-toolbar/dist/leaflet.draw-toolbar.css",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.css",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/images/zommer/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet/dist/leaflet.rotatedMarker.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar-src.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw-toolbar/dist/leaflet.draw-toolbar.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/color.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/pdf.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/pdf.worker.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leafletfunction.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mega-able:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "prod": {
              "browserTarget": "mega-able:build:prod"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "mega-able:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "mega-able:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/images/zommer/jquery.min.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/bootstrap.min.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet/dist/leaflet-src.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet/dist/leaflet.rotatedMarker.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar-src.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw-toolbar/dist/leaflet.draw-toolbar.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/color.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/pdf.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/pdf.worker.js",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leafletfunction.js"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "./node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "node_modules/font-awesome-scss/scss/font-awesome.scss",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw-toolbar/dist/leaflet.draw-toolbar.css",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-toolbar/dist/leaflet.toolbar.css",
              "src/assets/images/zommer/leaflet-draw/dist/leaflet.draw-src.css",
              "src/scss/style.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/marker-icon.png",
              "src/marker-icon-2x.png"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mega-able-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "mega-able:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "mega-able",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Below are all the various things I have tried based on Google searches.  All the commands were run from a Git Bash window unless otherwise specified:

1. npm install -g @angular/cli
2. npm install @angular/cli
3. ng update @angular/cli
4. ng update
5. ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
6. ng build

The same issue about the NgModule metadata was still present.  Next I tried the following:

1. npm remove webpack
2. npm install –save-dev @angular/cli@latest
3. npm cache clean –force
4. npm install
5. npm install –save-dev @angular/cli@latest
6. ng build

Issue persisted.  Next:

1. Manually deleted the node_modules folder
2. npm install
3. ng build

Issue persisted.  Next:

1. npm i -g @angular/cli@latest
2. Manually deleted node_modules folder
3. npm cache clear –force
4. npm cache verify
5. npm install
6. npm uninstall webpack
7. npm install –save-dev –save-exact @angular/cli@latest
8. ng build

Issue persisted.  Next:

1. Manually deleted the node_modules folder
2. Manually deleted the package-lock.json file
3. npm install
4. ng build

Issue persisted.  Next:

1. npm remove webpack
2. npm install –save-dev @angular/cli@latest
3. ng build

Issue persisted.  Next:

1. npm cache clean –force
2. npm install
3. npm install –save-dev @angular/cli@latest
4. ng build

Issue persisted.  Next:

1. Manually deleted the node_modules folder
2. Manually deleted the package-lock.json file
3. npm cache clean –force
4. npm install
5. npm install –save-dev @angular/cli@latest

Issue persisted.  Next:

1. Opened project in Visual Studio code
2. In the terminal window ran ng s
3. Confirmed compilation error
4. Opened the app.component.ts file
5. Added a blank space, removed it, and saved
6. Project automatically recompiled
7. Successfully access the site at http://localhost:4200
8. Closed Visual Studio Code
9. From a Git Bash window ran ng serve
10. Project failed to compile
11. Re-opened Visual Studio Code
12. Ran  ng serve from terminal window – error persisted
13. Resaved the app.component.ts file
14. Successfully accessed the site at http://localhost:4200
15. Restarted Visual Studio Code
16. Ran ng build from terminal window in Visual Studio Code – error returned
17. Resaved the app.component.ts file
18. Reran ng build command – error persisted

I'm at a lost of what else to try at this point and the dev team is off until at Tuesday for a holiday so any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated as I'm under some time constraints.  Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I think by now, you've already read this article: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798

If not, please read it and notice that the TS also modified the package.json file manually to resolve his issue.

Since we have not seen the actual error message in your build, we cannot deduce if the issue has the same circumstance as the one in the link. So my idea for you to resolve your issue is to do the following:

1. Remove the npm_modules folder
2. Move the package.json file to a backup folder (in case we need it back) - so this should not exist in your project folder as it will get generated when you do the next steps
3. Do the npm install
4. Do ng build
5. Do ng serve

After the above or if you get it working again I suggest to view the difference between your old package.json and new package.json file and let us know what you observed as it is always good to give back.

Comment: I have read that page and I have also included a screenshot of the actually error being displayed in the command window in the original question.  I am trying your specified steps now and will report back shortly on whether the issue was resolved.

Comment: I removed the npm_modules folder and moved the `package.json` file to a backup folder.  However, when I ran the **npm install** command, the `package.json` file was not re-created which caused the **ng build** command to output multiple errors about not being able to find modules (e.g. `Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\Users\\..."`)

Comment: I re-read through the link you provided and it seems like I had missed one of the possible fixes.  I had to update the `tsconfig.app.json` file to include the `files` array and specifically list `app/app.module.ts` in the array.  The previous error about not find the metadata has been resolved but now there is errors regarding a property not existing on the type '{}'.  This is definitely a different issue so I will start a new post if needed.  Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: nice good that you were able to resolve with some hints good job on you man

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this helps someone, in tsconfig.app.json (or wherever you define your tsconfig settings), this Angular compiler option, when set to true, causes various metadata failures even if files are not directly referenced in the `NgModule` metadata (simply importing a file in an `index.ts` is enough).

Individual files / types can be surpressed with the `// @dynamic` comment, or ... you can check to make sure that `strictMetadataEmit` is set to false:

tsconfig.json:

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": false
}
```

In my case, this had been set to true at some point, so Angular was failing on metadata for classes that had nothing to do with module defs. Setting it to `false` (which is the default, as specified here: https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options) fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I likely had a dependency error. I tried everything from [this link](https://stack247.wordpress.com/2018/09/07/angular-all-possible-solutions-for-no-ngmodule/) but nothing worked. I had to do the following to successfully build after updating from 6.2 to 7:

1. Delete node modules folder.
2. Run the following command: `cmd /C "set "NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1" && npx @angular/cli@7 update @angular/cli@7 @angular/core@7" --force`. (Basically the same update command from the official angular update guide but with the `--force` flag.)
3. Run the following command: `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`. If this fails you may have to use the `--force` flag again.

Environment: Windows 10, Node 10.9, Nvm 1.1.9,

Comment: This worked for me, but you should note that you can't run the 2. command if you don't have node_modules. You'll get an error `Package '@angular/cli' is not a dependency.` You need to npm install first.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple trailing commas in your `@NgModule's` declarations and imports arrays. Delete those and see if that solves it.

Comment: The '@' symbol was originally there...I must have accidentally deleted it.  However, I have re-added it (and updated the original question showing how the app.module.ts file is now) but when I run the ng build command I still get the same error.

Comment: I don't see any reference to `AppComponent` in the `index.html` file, just a `<app-root>` tag.  I have updated the original question with the contents of the `index.html` file as well as the `angular.json` file as I can't see anything wrong with this file.

Comment: Thanks anways...I appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

It should be @NgModule not just NgModule.

```
@NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        AdminComponent,
        AdminComponent1,
        AuthComponent,
        BreadcrumbsComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        SharedModule,
        NgProgressModule,
        SimpleNotificationsModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,


      ],
      providers: [MenuItems, ServicesProvider, AuthGuardService, SupperAdmin, AuthLoginService,  NgProgressModule, ConfigService],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

Metadata is used to decorate a class so that it can configure the expected behavior of the class. We leverage the Typescript syntax and attach the classes with metadata using the decorator feature. To make a class as a component, we add the @Component decorator, as shown in the following code:

```
@Component({...})
export class FirstComponent {...}
```

Comment: The '@' symbol was originally there...I must have accidentally deleted it.  However, I have re-added it (and updated the original question showing how the app.module.ts file is now) but when I run the ng build command I still get the same error.

Comment: Did you try deleting your node modules and re-installing them using npm install

Comment: Yes, that was the third thing I tried.  I also deleted the node_modules folder during fixes 4 & 5, as well as deleting the node_modules folder along with the package-lock.json file as part of the steps of fix 8 listed in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by updating the **tsconfig.app.json** file to include the **files** property and specifically listing `app/app.module.ts` in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried every Stack Overflow suggestion on this error, on all the many posts about this. Nothing worked, but I found the solution for me.

It was this line in a component:

```
@Output() public editItemEvent : EventEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

I had used the wrong package for importing EventEmitter

```
import { EventEmitter } from 'protactor';
```

Changing it to

```
import { EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
```

and

```
@Output() public editItemEvent : EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

... fixed it.